# How to understand the shuffle scheme in tensorflow.data.Dataset() in TFRecords format

Tags: tensorflow

Take the `ImageNet` dataset as an example, it has about 1280000 images/samples. We save it as `TFRecords` format. Suppose each `.tfrecord` has 10000 samples and finally 128 `.tfrecord` files will be generated. Then in training stage for CNN, after one epoch, we need to shuffle the dataset, in general, we need to shuffle the indices of the images, and sequentially take the images according to the shuffled indices.

The images in one `.tfrecord` is fixed, i.e., the `1.tfrecord` has the 0~9999 images, `2.tfrecord` has the 10000~19999 images, etc. After the image indices are shuffled, suppose we need to take two images with indices of `5000` and `15000`, we need to open the first two `.tfrecord` files, and take the two images according to the indices. This operation will cost much memory and spend much time.

So Is this reasonable? How did it actually do for the shuffle operation? I'm not sure if I correctly understood the `tf.data.Dataset()` scheme. If convenient, could you please give some advice? Thanks.